# Script in unity won't change

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a script that uses .AddForce to move a ball. when i use it on the z axis, it works fine, but when i move on the x axis, it goes way too fast. The speed used to be 300 for the x axis, but i changed it to 50 for both. force on the x axis is still too high, and it won't change.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class ball_movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody ballmovement;
    public float zforce = 50f;
    public float xforce = 50f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            //ball moves right
            ballmovement.AddForce(0, 0, zforce * Time.deltaTime, 
ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
         if (Input.GetKey("s"))
         {
            //ball moves left
            ballmovement.AddForce(0, 0, -zforce * Time.deltaTime, 
ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            //ball moves forward
            ballmovement.AddForce(xforce, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime, 
ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            //ball moves right
            ballmovement.AddForce(-xforce, 0, 0 * Time.deltaTime, 
ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you are not affecting * Time.deltaTime for the xforce. Hope it helps

Comment: @M106 You can accept the answer if that's the issue